# restore the modal original state in FormArray on "Cancel Change" button clicked in angular5

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on Angular 5 app and using FormArray of reactive forms.
when user make some changes in one or more FormGroup and later change his mind and click on "Cancel change" button than how to restore the initial state of component Model??

I tried looking for this on the angular official website and 
on stackOverflow but did not find anything similar to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, the reset function was not what I was looking for so I end-up using the below function for reseting the formarray,

```
purgeForm(form: FormArray) {
    while (0 !== form.length) {
      form.removeAt(0);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have original form object state.

```
let original = {
   fname: '',
   lname: '',
   date: ''
};
```

Take a copy from original object

```
let copied = Object.assign({}, original);
```

You can use the copied object inside the Form Group & Form Array.

When click reset, you can use original object.

Comment: I do have a original copy save in another varaible as you have mentioned. but  can you elaborate on "When click reset, you can use original object." ??  I mean,  I do not think, we can pass the original modal to the reset API of FormArray?  can we ?

Comment: What i mean is, you can assign the copied object = original. when we click reset. i.e copied = Object.assign({}, original);

Answer (score 0):

This is how you reset:

```
const originalState = {foo: 'bar'};

public myForm = this.fb.group(originalState);

resetMyForm() {
  this.myForm.reset(originalState);
}
```

Calling just `reset()` will set all controls to `null`.